# Como imprimir los valores de esta consulta en php SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ';') FROM wpzj_postmeta GROUP BY post_id

Tags: php, array, select, woocommerce, sql

Buen dia para todos. Soy nuevo en programación y siempre he impreso en php tablas creadas por mi mismo. Pero ahora tengo que mostrar los datos de una tabla de **woocommerce** que me resulta mas dificil. Me recomendaron usar esta consulta:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ';') FROM wpzj_postmeta GROUP BY post_id`

La cual me arroja los siguientes valores:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ';')
wc_order_mu1E3yHWL1BIs;0;cod;Pago contra entrega;1...
wc_order_q6QzumKes99Uw;0;epayco;Paga con ePayco  (...
wc_order_CW5bqQVJLVDC5;0;cod;Pago contra entrega;1...
wc_order_GwNATYyYqE7b4;0;cod;Pago contra entrega;1...
wc_order_soO6a7I8mn1Vr;0;epayco;Paga con ePayco  (...
wc_order_jeY8lStOgVD6t;0;cod;Pago contra entrega;1...
wc_order_prtdIob2ZCZ7D;0;epayco;Paga con ePayco  (...
```

El problema es que en php no se como acceder a cada uno de los datos para poder mostrárselos en una tabla al usuario. Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Tienes que decirnos qué código PHP estás usando para hacer la consulta y para leer el resultado, porque en PHP hay dos APIs diferentes para consultar la base de datos (mysqli y PDO) y la lectura de datos es distinta en cada una. Convendria que pongas un alias a la columna para que la lectura posterior te sea más fácil.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta este es el código que estoy usando


`$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxxx","xxxxxxxxx");

if (!$mysqli) {
echo "Error: no se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
die();
}

       $descarga = $mysqli->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ';') FROM wpzj_postmeta GROUP BY post_id");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hace esa sentencia SQL es crear un string a partir de todos los valores de un post que hay en postmeta.

Cada una de las lineas las puedes convertir en arrays con explode:

```
$valores = explode(';', $linea_devuelta);
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Podrías decirme como accedo a la linea?. Antes yo accedía a cierto dato desde la misma consulta con el where pero con esta nueva consulta estoy muy confundido porque no se hacerlo con php, es decir antes yo seleccionaba el dato con select y where y luego en php extraía el dato pero con este tipo de consulta me confundo. Perdón soy muy nuevo en esto

Comment: es un array, $valores[0] es una linea de la bbdd. Asi que $valores[0][0] es el primer elemento de la primera fila. Puedes usar foreach. https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php